# Run login script anytime I login on a cluster via ssh

Tags: ssh, login-script

I would like to know how can I write a login script restricted just to a certain environment. To be clear, I need a script that runs certain commands only when I remotely access a computing cluster using ssh. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check for SSH_CONNECTION variable in your shell startup script and execute commands if this variable is set. It works in OpenSSH and dropbear.